# Using IVSInvisibleEditor and IVSPersistDocData but how do i release them?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I am using the IVsInvisibleEditor in a custom tool window to load up a t4 file into a hosted vs editor.  I call the IVsInvisibleEditorManager.RegisterInvisibleEditor method passing in the t4 file like they do [here](https://github.com/yysun/Git-Source-Control-Provider/blob/master/ToolWindowWithEditor.cs).  I then use the GetDocData method to get the file contents and then set them to the buffer of the editor.  I save changes from the editor by casting the result of getdocdata to an IVsPersistDocData instance and call the save method.  On closing of the tool window I try to clean up resources by calling close on the IVsPersistDocData instance.  When I  try to open the tool window again for the same file, I get an exception when trying to call getdocdata on the invisible editor again.  If I don't call the close on the IVsPersistDocData it works.  How do I properly close all these resources (IVsInvisibleEditor, IVsInvisibleEditorManager, IVsPersistDocData) so I don't get exceptions when I try to use them again?

Comment: Do you face an actual problem or is it just good manners :-) ? IVSpersistDocData.Close closes the document. You should call this if you really want to close the doc. Otherwise if you're running on .NET, you don't need to do anything special (if you keep references on interfaces, because if you have IntPtr then you want to release them)

Comment: Well, I do get an exception because I think the IVsInvisibleEditorManager.RegisterInvisibleEditor is adding the file I open to the running document table and when I just use the close method on IVSPersistDocData I am not sure if that is removing it from the running document table, I guess my biggest issue is trying to understand how all these pieces fit together, I have read the MSDN docs on the subject but it has not helped.  Do you know of any better resources for trying to learn this stuff?

Comment: LearnVSX (http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/03/17/LearnVSXNowPart17.aspx) used to be quite good but it's not been updated. Otherwise some parts of the official doc are good: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165336.aspx (the "Editors" section for example). Also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsx/ Otherwise the VSX forum on MSDN has knowledgeable people around, you can try it. Note you can dump the ROT using IVsRunningDocumentTable.

Comment: In regards to resources, most everything is outdated or undocumented. The only approach I've had that works is to buy Reflector and step through Visual Studio's source itself.

Comment: @JoshVarty I have used the .reflector product from redgate in the past but did not know you could debug and step through Visual Studio code with it, [this](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/guest-post) is going to be extremely useful!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IVsInvisibleEditor` doesn't have a Close method on it because it just uses COM reference counting: when the object gets it's final call to IUnknown.Release(), it uses that as it's cue to close the underlying file. If you're writing your extension in C++, then this is easy: just make sure you Release it and you're fine. But I'm guessing you're writing this in managed code, which is a lot harder. The CLR makes dealing with objects like this a pain. I'm going to assume you're not a COM marshalling expert, so I apologize for the long discussion, but it's important to understand how this all works.

*Background:* whenever you try to use a COM object from managed code, the CLR creates what's known as a "Runtime Callable Wrapper", or RCW. This is a small managed object that is the wrapper around the native object. Internally, it holds onto the IUnknown pointer, and it "owns" the AddRef/Release for that object. The idea is when managed code is no longer using the RCW, the RCW gets garbage collected and when that happens the CLR then calls Release() on the underlying object.

When you call `IVsInvisibleEditorManager.RegisterInvisibleEditor`, the native code in VS will hand back a pointer to the object back to managed code. The CLR is then wrapping the object in a RCW, which means that unless we take special steps with `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`, the invisible editor will float around until the GC determines that the RCW is gone and it's time to Release() it. Not what you need.

So, just call Marshal.ReleaseComObject, and be done, right? Wrong! In general, [Marshal.ReleaseComObject should be considered dangerous](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx) because the CLR has another tricky behavior here. Imagine you were to open the invisible editor for a file, and while you have it open another component in Visual Studio also opens the same file and the manager handed back the same native instance of `IVsInvisibleEditor`. You already had your RCW for the instance of the native object. The CLR, for this other component, will go "a ha! somebody else already has that object" and hands them the same RCW as you have. If they called `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` and destroyed the COM object, that would mean your object you have in hand just got zombied. This is why `ReleaseComObject` is dangerous: you can only call it if you know you are the only person holding onto that RCW, but by default the CLR shares RCWs between anybody who needs one.

This is why you can't use `IVsInvisibleEditorManager` correctly from managed code: when you call the `RegisterInvisibleEditor`, you're getting a shared RCW back. You cannot call `ReleaseComObject on it without potentially breaking somebody else. There's no easy way to opt into getting a unique RCW.

The first step to properly addressing this problem is defining our own interface for `IVsInivisibleEditorManager`. This is how we define it in some parts of managed VS code:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("14439CDE-B6CF-4DD6-9615-67E8B3DF380D")]
internal interface IIntPtrReturningVsInvisibleEditorManager
{
    int RegisterInvisibleEditor(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszMkDocument,
        IVsProject pProject,
        uint dwFlags,
        IVsSimpleDocFactory pFactory,
        out IntPtr ppEditor);
}
```

This you can just stick in your assembly, no problems. This is how it's defined in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell interop assembly, but with one critical difference: instead of the ppEditor parameter being a COM object (which will get us a shared RCW), we just get an IntPtr back for the object. The CLR will leave that untouched which is the key: we need to control how that gets converted to an RCW. What you do then is first get the `IVsInvisibleEditorManager` interface, then cast that to your own interface. This works because casting RCWs to COM interfaces is magic: as long as the underlying object says it supports the interface (looked up by the GUID specified), then the CLR fakes it and says the RCW can be cast to the interface -- even one you defined yourself. Then, you can call `RegisterInvisibleEditor` and get an IntPtr back, and then create a unique RCW for it. Here's the code to get the doc data:

```
var invisibleEditorManager = (IIntPtrReturningVsInvisibleEditorManager)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsInvisibleEditorManager));
var invisibleEditorPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(invisibleEditorManager.RegisterInvisibleEditor(filePath, null, 0, null, out invisibleEditorPtr));

try
{
    this.invisibleEditor = (IVsInvisibleEditor)Marshal.GetUniqueObjectForIUnknown(invisibleEditorPtr);

    var docDataPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(invisibleEditor.GetDocData(fEnsureWritable: 0, riid: typeof(IVsTextLines).GUID, ppDocData: out docDataPtr));

    try
    {
        var docData = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(docDataPtr);

        // use docData how you want, probably by getting the text of it               
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.Release(docDataPtr);
    }
}
finally
{
    // Since we have a unique RCW holding onto the object, we must release our direct pointer as well
    Marshal.Release(invisibleEditorPtr);
}
```

Those finally blocks are critical: when we get an IntPtr representing a COM object back, the object has already been AddRef'ed for us. When we create the RCW, the native object gets another AddRef(). if we don't call Release on the native pointer, then we'll leak that too. But after the code above, this.invisibleEditor holds the unique RCW that we can later use. Once you're ready to close this whole thing, all you have to do is call:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(this.invisibleEditor)
```

And the underlying COM object will be destroyed immediately.

Comment: You are correct, I am not a COM expert and I am using managed code but the long discussion is greatly appreciated!  This solved my problem perfectly and explains a lot.  I no longer get the exception when I reopen the file multiple times.

Comment: I've long intended to write this up, and your question became the forcing function. :-)

Comment: And the next questions of course are: how many interfaces among the hundreds available from the VS SDK should be redefined this way when using managed code? what are they? why is this never documented? no offense and nice answer but it's sad to discover these things here :-)

Comment: This is the only one I'm aware of off of the top of my head. Good point about the diagnostics, I'll send some e-mail internally.